# jQuery drop down menu position while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm new to jQuery and learning jQuery concepts. Currently, I'm trying to design a custom drop down menu which has long list items. I wanted to scroll the menus while mouse over to the main menu. I'm trying to customize the CSS with the jquery scroll menu which described [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/) with a new look and feel.

I have tried the script, but i found some issues in it. You can check it in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bUxDE/1/) . While initial mouseover to the first list item, the drop down list items are not displaying at all (In an initial page load.) Secondly, the width of the second level UL item is getting hidden.

Can anyone please check the fiddle and correct it? Also, please let me know, where I did wrong, so that I will try to correct myself in the future.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Your problem is the CSS. Using the original CSS from the css-tricks website fixed your issue.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem, but i wanted to try to use it in the custom designed css. you may check the screenshots [link](http://imgur.com/EzHZ2,caqT8#0) and [link](http://imgur.com/EzHZ2,caqT8#1) to get a clear look on the issue when I tried the script in a plain page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out maybe helpful

```
ul.dropdown li:last-child a
{
  border-right: none;
} /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover
{
  background: #F3D673;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
ul.dropdown li a:hover{background: #F3D673;}
```

JQuery:

```
.mousemove(function(e) {
                var offset = $container.offset();
                var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) -   ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier)+50;
                if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                    $list.css("top", -relativeY);
                    $list.css("zIndex", "-1"); //add this line 
                };
            });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bUxDE/22/)

Comment: Thanks @afshin, but I have tried the modifications in a plain html and still has padding problem for the drop down lists. Please check my comment for the initial question. Thanks again. :)

Comment: now, I'm facing another problem. Just check this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bUxDE/25/). the text or any content in the div after the main div is getting wrapped around the drop down menu. How can I solve this?

Comment: <div style="position:absolute;width:100%; height:200px;background:#333;color:#fff">