# Fixed footer with 100 height absolute position body and jquery scroll menu

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a new website with 1024 width framework. I need 100% width top header, header, menu and 100% width of footer. But I need 1024 px width content placeholder. I'm trying to set 100% height content. Say, if the content placeholder has less content, the footer need to stick to the bottom of the page, and if the content placeholder has more content the entire page need to be scrolled. here is the code sample:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background: #dddedf url('Images/top-header-bg.png') repeat-x top left;position: relative;">
<div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
                <!--Top Header Section-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #fff url('Images/header-bg.png') no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
                <!--Header Section-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; background: #0D9B8C url('Images/menu-bg.png') repeat-x top left;
    position: fixed;">
    <div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 30px;">
                    <!--Menu Section-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 160px; height: 100%; margin-bottom: -40px;">
    <div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; background: #fff url('Images/body-bg.png') repeat-x fixed top left;
        height: 100%;">
        <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
<!--Main Content Section-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background: #dddedf url('Images/footer-bg.png') repeat-x bottom left;
    position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
    <div style="width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
               <!--Footer Section-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to set the main content placeholder absolute position because of the jquery scroll menu. If i set relative position, the text inside the main content placeholder gets wrapped while accessing the menu. For more details about this problem, please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933070/jquery-drop-down-menu-position-while-scrolling). 
 Here is a [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g2FXn/show/) and this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2FXn/) for the same. Did I do something wrong? Solutions and suggestions are most welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider using Twitter's bootstrap? It's great for responsive designs, and fixing elements to the top and bottom of pages.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you @Ollie. But I really don't want to use bootstrap. Because my framework (an asp.net web application) needs a max width of 1024px and they (customer) doesn't want either 940px or 1200px framework. So, I'm struggling to get what I wanted and what the client needs. I also tried with this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/g2FXn/1/). Did I do something wrong in css? Thanks again.

Comment: You can modify bootstrap to just use the widths that you require. Have a look through the scaffolding pages in the docs and set the page up so its no longer responsive. However, you should be able to argue the case for a responsive design with these different size options as it allows the site to look great on a much wider selection of screen sizes.

Comment: Okay. thanks. Will trying to go with bootstrap... Hope all will be fine. :) I will post my solution when I'm done.